# Stop Rails server in new AWS Cloud 9 IDE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, ide, cloud9-ide

I am just starting to learn Rails in the new AWS Cloud 9 on a Mac and I cannot stop the Rails server. The instructions say to use `Control+c` but in the Cloud9 terminal with Rails running this just writes:

```
^[c
```

...and then creates a new line and does nothing.

I have also tried `killall -9 rails` but this just writes it in the terminal and again creates a new line but does nothing. Any help here please? Here is what my Cloud 9 terminal currently looks like:

```
ec2-user:~/ruby_projects (master) $ rails s -b $IP -p $PORT
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.1 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.12.0 (ruby 2.4.1-p111), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://127.0.0.1:8080
Use Ctrl-C to stop
^[c
c

^[c
killall -9 rails
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> doesn't do the trick then just close the terminal and that should kill all ongoing processes in that terminal.

You can verify that it killed it by running `ps aux | grep "rails"` and then checking if there are any entries. If there is one find the process ID and then kill it (or you could just kill it with `ps aux | grep -ie rails | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9`).